# The double pointer points to the int variable to overwrite the memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, int, double

I put the code directly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main()
{
    struct A test;
    double *p = (double *)&(test.a);
    *p = 5;

    printf("variable a: %d\n", &test.a);
    printf("variable b: %d\n", &test.b);
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code in centos7, the compiler is `gcc4.8.5`.And my computer uses little ending to store.

As you see, the memory of variable `b` will be overwritten, I expected `a` is `0x0000 0005` and `b` is `0x0000 0000`.

But the answer is:

```
variable a: 0
variable b: 1075052544
```

Why variable `a` is `0x 0000 0000` and `b` is `0x4014 0000`?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Also, the `double` 5 corresponds to the 64-bit integer `0x4014000000000000` so you can probably figure out what's happening. Hint: `double` can be larger than `int`.

Comment: You get unexpected result because you lied to your compiler, and it figured a way to get back at you. You told the compiler that `&(test.a)` is an address of a `double`, but it is an address of an integer.

Comment: You can twiddle with the optimization settings and get your compiler to compile code where the result is something *else* as well.

Comment: @Bathsheba just writing here that the output doesn't match the code, so, why did you reverse my downvote?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Oops. Did not see that. I've withdrawn my upvote. Luckily the answer stays the same.

Comment: Your code's got an error... you meant to output `test.a`, but copied wrong code here, which outputs `&test.a`. Both are ill-defined examples.

Comment: I know that should not use the double pointer to the int variable, I just want to test the memory coverage.

Comment: @unwind Thanks, you are right.The `double 5` corresponds to the 64-bit integer `0x40140000 00000000`.So I get variable `b` is `0x 40140000`, verify that my idea is correct, the value of the variable `b` is indeed covered. But I just don't konw why `double 5` corresponds to the 64-bit integer `0x40140000 00000000`?How it is stored?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  This is a test, I just want to verify that the other half of the 4 bytes does become the value of the variable `b`.

Comment: @UKeeySDis That's the thing, though - you can't rely on the results of a test if there is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala In fact this is a fixed value, because the value of the variable b is a double pointer to a value after the remaining 4 bytes.

Comment: @UKeeySDis Read some basic material on computer floating-point, such as [Wikipedia's entry on IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: The code is a strict aliasing violation and therefore completely undefined behavior. It is pointless to reason about the effects of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

You can't dereference `p` once you've set it to the address of something that is not a `double` type.

To see what your compiler has done with this input, check the generated assembly.

Comment: In my computer, `int`  occupies 4 bytes, `double` occupies 8 bytes, I use double pointer to int and assignment, it should override the value of variable b, so I think b should be 5, a should be 0.And `1075052544` is a fixed value that does not change with each run or change optimization.

Comment: You can think what you want to think. That's obviously not what is happening. The fact remains the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: The double 5 corresponds to the 64-bit integer `0x4014000000000000`.So I get `b` is `0x4014 0000`, the value of the variable b is the other half of the 4 bytes.

Comment: @UKeeySDis: you could verify that by setting a 64 bit integer to a given value, a double to another value, and calling `memcmp`. All perfectly defined behaviour.

Comment: This is really a good idea, I verify it.But why the double 5 corresponds to the 64-bit integer `0x4014000000000000`?How it is stored?Thank you very much.

Comment: @UKeeySDis As soon as you invoke undefined behavior, you can no longer reason about your program. The compiler may optimize the machine code in completely crazy ways and the program may run amok. You cannot predict anything and you cannot expect anything. Which is why undefined behavior is always a severe bug. Read up about "the strict aliasing rule".

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

Clang compiler generate warning message:

```
source_file.c:13:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("%d\n", &test.a);
            ~~     ^~~~~~~
source_file.c:14:20: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("%d\n", &test.b);
            ~~     ^~~~~~~
```